# How can I convert a crawlspace to a basement?

Tags: basement

I have walk in crawl space. The celing hight is any where from 5ft to 9 ft. It is all dirt and NO concrete. The plumbing and HVAC lines running all over the places. All and all I have about 700 to 900 soft which can be converted to basement. I have a closet on the first floor which could be the access to the basement.
I need some direction where should I start. I will not be doing all the work by my self. I live in Charlotte NC area.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live? If the plan is to use the space as living space, most code will require a minimum ceiling height. That's usually 7'. So you either have to accept that you can only use a portion of the crawlspace, or you have to dig down deeper.

To dig down deeper, you need to bring in a structural engineer to figure out how to underpin the existing footers. That's typically done with a buttress wall a few feet in from the existing footer. So you will loose some perimeter space due to that.

If you have HVAC and mechanicals everywhere, keep in mind the time and costs to re-route all of that as well.

Enclosing a crawlspace is a good idea, but if the goal is ultimately to mainly get more livable space, you may want to investigate an above-ground addition instead. It may ultimately be easier (and cheaper) to do that rather than convert a crawlspace.

Answer (score 0):

Finished basements are great, but, especially in an old house, they can and will flood from time to time. It's inevitable; design accordingly. This means no wooden walls, no drywall, no carpet, no hardwood flooring, etc. Don't use anything that would be destroyed by standing water. Here's how I would do it:

Level the dirt floor. Build a drain in the center that's 3.5" above the current level of the dirt. The drain should empty to a sump pump or preferably daylight somewhere out of the house (the sump pump will fail during a power outage, which may happen during a flood). Put down a polyethylene vapor barrier over the dirt and seal it to the crawlspace walls and the drain. Pour a concrete slab over the poly to serve as a subfloor, finishing it at the same level as the drain. Optional: if you want the basement to be much more comfortable in winter and a little less comfortable in summer, before pouring the slab, put down 2-4" of rigid EPS foam insulation boards between the dirt and the poly vapor barrier, and raise the drain accordingly.

Then insulate the walls. Glue 4"+ of rigid EPS foam insulation boards right up against the crawlspace walls. Use two layers of 2" boards, and stagger the seams. Then seal the rim joists with foam boards and spray foam, making sure to completely encapsulate them. Do not use fiberglass batts for this. After that, you can cover the walls with cementboard, screwed through the foam and into the walls with masonry screws (e.g. Tapcons).

Next, determine the layout. Use the sections with a 5-foot ceiling height as closets, and the 8+ ceiling height areas as living space or whatever.

Now build your interior partition walls, if any. Build them out of 6" thick concrete blocks instead of wooden studs, which will rot and mold in the presence of standing water. Then, finish off the exterior walls and the interior partition walls with lime plaster, not drywall, drywall mud or gypsum plaster, as those will disintegrate in the presence of standing water. Since the walls will be relatively flat and straight, you won't need much plaster. It should go quickly.

You can use drywall for the ceiling, or paneling, or whatever. The ceiling is unlikely to encounter water, so making it waterproof is less critical.

Finally, install the flooring. You can polish and stain the concrete or install tile. No carpet or hardwood. If you've insulate beneath the slab, it will be much less cold to your feet anyway. If you want soft flooring, use removable rugs over the concrete or tile.

The result of all of this work is that you will have a comfortable, dry, and waterproof finished basement that will not be destroyed if it does indeed flood. You can just wait for the water to drain and the basement to dry out, and everything will be fine.